# Localhost endpoint overrides 0.0.0.0 endpoint when two kestrel instances are launched

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, endpoint, kestrel

I have two kestrel instances running in the same process.
The first instance is listening on endpoint http://0.0.0.0:80/ and provides the endpoint for signalR. This endpoint should be accessible from all IPs (therefore I usede the 0.0.0.0 endpoint).

The second kestrel instance is listening on http://localhost:8080/ and provides the endpoint of a WebAPI. This endpoint should only be accessible from the same machine (therefore I used the localhost endpoint).

Before I set up the second instance (on port 8080) everything was working fine. The adress http://localhost:80/ was accessible from any IP-Address. But after setting up the second instance (on port 80), the first instance wasn't reachable anymore from another IP-Address than localhost.

After setting the endpoint for both kestrel instances to 0.0.0.0 the first instance was accessible again for all IP-Addresses.

I set up the webhosts like this:

```
mWebHost = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseUrls(STARTUP_URL)
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseStartup<MyStartupClass>()
              .ConfigureServices(dependencyExchangeContainerService.RegisterMefClasses)
                .ConfigureLogging(
                    (context, builder) =>
                        {
                            builder.AddDebug();
                            builder.AddFilter(level => level >= LogLevel.Warning).AddConsole();
                        })
                .Build();
            mWebHost.StartAsync();
```

Both kestrel instances have a different startup class.

I expect, that the first instance is reachable from any IP and the second instance only from localhost.
At the moment it seems like the localhost endpoint overrides the settings of the 0.0.0.0 endpoint.

Comment: are you saying both processes are trying to listen on port 80?

Comment: No. Both kestrel instances are listening on the correct port. The only problem is, that the first instance isn't reachable from the outside (e.g. another computer). If you do the request on the same host, everything works fine. If both kestrel endpoints are set to 0.0.0.0 then the first instance is reachable again from another computer.

The reason for these different endpoints is, that I don't want to make the second instance (on port 8080) public for the outside world. Only the first instance (port 80) should be visible for the outside.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I have to say sorry! This problem doesn't exist.

I'm in a complicated network environment where multiple hardware firewalls and a wifi connection is included. And I thought that the firewall were already patched with the correct ports but they wasn't. And after I patched the DLL with the new endpoint, my iPad has established a connection with a different router (where the firewall was patched) and everything was fine.